# What happens to variables when Android activity is destroyed and foreground service is still running?

Tags: android, service, foreground

For destroyed, I mean the activity is in background and cleaned up by Android due to memory shortage.

1.
If my activity and foreground service are using the same process, is this scenario (activity destroyed and foreground service running) possible?

2. If that's possible, I understand all of my variables in the activity are cleaned up, but what about static variables and methods in a class that both my activity and foreground service reference?
3. If my foreground service is holding a reference to the activity and the activity is destroyed, will my variable holding that reference reset to null or will it still hold a reference with corrupt object?

Comment: Variables are *not* "set to null" automatically - *objects have no intrinsic knowledge of what variables/fields refer to them.* Any such field must be re-assigned (to `null`) by something that has external knowledge. (An object cannot be GC'ed even though it is "closed or disposed or otherwise invalid" until there are no more strong-references; [static] variables form strong-references, regardless of the internal state of the object.)